# IntelliJ IDEA causes NoSuchMethodErrors in GRPC/Netty

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, guava, grpc

I've been using IntelliJ 2017.01 Ultimate and gradle to develop Java applications using GRPC for IPC for a while now. Recently, I found that when I start the application via IntelliJ run configuration I get the following error:

```
io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler onHeadersRead
WARNING: Exception in onHeadersRead()
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createUnstarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;
    at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil$3.get(GrpcUtil.java:490)
    at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil$3.get(GrpcUtil.java:487)
    at io.grpc.internal.StatsTraceContext.<init>(StatsTraceContext.java:92)
    at io.grpc.internal.StatsTraceContext.newClientContext(StatsTraceContext.java:106)
    at io.grpc.internal.StatsTraceContext.<clinit>(StatsTraceContext.java:64)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl.methodDetermined(ServerImpl.java:387)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.onHeadersRead(NettyServerHandler.java:196)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.access$300(NettyServerHandler.java:90)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler$FrameListener.onHeadersRead(NettyServerHandler.java:474)
    at io.grpc.netty.FixedHttp2ConnectionDecoder$FrameReadListener.onHeadersRead(FixedHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:320)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger$1.onHeadersRead(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:65)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader$1.processFragment(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:461)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readHeadersFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:468)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.processPayloadState(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:253)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:160)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger.readFrame(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:41)
    at io.grpc.netty.FixedHttp2ConnectionDecoder.decodeFrame(FixedHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:119)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$FrameDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:341)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:401)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:642)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:565)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:479)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:441)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

followed by

```
io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler onStreamError
WARNING: Stream Error
io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception$StreamException: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createUnstarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.streamError(Http2Exception.java:147)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.newStreamException(NettyServerHandler.java:452)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.onHeadersRead(NettyServerHandler.java:211)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.access$300(NettyServerHandler.java:90)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler$FrameListener.onHeadersRead(NettyServerHandler.java:474)
    at io.grpc.netty.FixedHttp2ConnectionDecoder$FrameReadListener.onHeadersRead(FixedHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:320)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger$1.onHeadersRead(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:65)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader$1.processFragment(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:461)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readHeadersFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:468)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.processPayloadState(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:253)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:160)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger.readFrame(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:41)
    at io.grpc.netty.FixedHttp2ConnectionDecoder.decodeFrame(FixedHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:119)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$FrameDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:341)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:401)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:642)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:565)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:479)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:441)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createUnstarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;
    at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil$3.get(GrpcUtil.java:490)
    at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil$3.get(GrpcUtil.java:487)
    at io.grpc.internal.StatsTraceContext.<init>(StatsTraceContext.java:92)
    at io.grpc.internal.StatsTraceContext.newClientContext(StatsTraceContext.java:106)
    at io.grpc.internal.StatsTraceContext.<clinit>(StatsTraceContext.java:64)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl.methodDetermined(ServerImpl.java:387)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.onHeadersRead(NettyServerHandler.java:196)
    ... 29 more
```

As soon as I run the application from command line I don't get any of these errors. I guess it's a problem with guava and the classpath set by IntelliJ, but I have no idea on how to fix this.

My build.gradle contains:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':synthesis')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160810'
    compile group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna', version: '4.3.0'
    //compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '19.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.2.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.2.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createUnstarted()` has existed since Guava 15. It seems like you're using an older version. Try running `./gradlew dependencies` to see where the older version is coming from.

I expect you are getting a dependency to `guava-jdk5` (instead of an old dependency on `guava`). You can [exclude the dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies):

```
dependencies {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
```

Comment: When running my project with ./gradlew there were no problems at all. The problems only came only when running the project from IntelliJ Idea. It seems like IntelliJ adds an old version of guava to the classpath. However, this line of code fixed it

Comment: If you have both `guava` and `guava-jdk5` in your classpath, then you'll end up using one "randomly" based on how the classpath is constructed. IntelliJ probably listed the classpath slightly differently to trigger the problem, but the problem could just as easily impacted Gradle and not IntelliJ.